# implode array of dates and insert into a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, arrays, date, format, implode

I have a major problem trying to implode an array of dates and then inserting them into a database unlike text and integers or doubles which seem easy to do...how do I go about doing this? The date format is "Y/m/d".

I am imploding various arrays and then inserting them into a database to then later retrieve them and explode them into their original arrays. I want to do this with an array of dates but I need to format them before inserting.

How can I format the dates in the array and then pass it to the implode() function to insert it into the MySL database?

The structure of the array is as follows:

```
    $array = (
               [0] => 2012/09/13
               [1] => 2008/03/20
               [2] => 2006/12/21
             )

I have tried inserting arrays after imploding the date variable but to no avail. It just prints "Array" in my mysql database - i am using PHPmyadmin - please help me figure out whats going down! thanks!
```

UPDATES: This is the code I am using:

```
        $arrlength = count($day);
    $arrlength1 = count($month);
    $arrlength2 = count($year);
$t = 0;
$line = Array();
for($x=0; $x<$arrlength; $x++){
    for($y=0; $y<$arrlength1; $y++){
        for($z=0; $z<$arrlength2; $z++){
            $line = $day[$x]." ".$month[$z]." ".$year[$y];

            }
        }       
    //$line = $day[$x]." 2"; 
    //$x++;
    }
$line = implode(",",$line);
echo $line;
```

Comment: There is no difference between dates and text in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert multiple dates into a single DB field of a single row?

I would suggest creating an additional table and inserting one row per every date in the array. That would be the best solution and best practice.

But if you want to continue with saving them in a single field/row, use implode()/explode(), or serialize()/unserialize().

Ok let's sopose you have a field named `dates` in your table, and it is of type varchar or text with enough length.

```
<?php

$dates=array('2012/09/13','2008/03/20','2006/12/21');

// save them
$sql="INSERT INTO event(title, dates) VALUES ('dummy title', '".implode(",",$dates)."')";
$conn->query($sql);

// recover them
$sql="SELECT * FROM event";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  // split them again into array 
  $dates=explode(",",$row["dates"]);
}


?>
```

But as I said the first time, ideally it would be more correct from a database point of view to create a secondary table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event_date` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `event_id` (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `event_date`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `event_date_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `event` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

And ofcourse in this case, before saving a date into `event_date`, you would first have to convert its format, example:

```
<?php

$original_date='2006/12/21';
$date_object=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $original_date);
if ($date_object) {
  $date_for_mysql=$date_object->format('Y-m-d');
}

?>
```

Comment: i tried both methods and they don't work! does PHP my admin allow multiple dates to be inserted as an array?

Comment: first of all, please provide example of the code you are running, and then also example of the database tables you have, then we can talk more, and no, you cannot save an array into a varchar or date field, but you can convert it to string with the methods I've told you, implode or serialize, and then save it

Comment: this is the code I used -  $arrlength = count($day);
 $arrlength1 = count($month);
 $arrlength2 = count($year);
$t = 0;
$line = Array();
for($x=0; $x<$arrlength; $x++){
 for($y=0; $y<$arrlength1; $y++){
  for($z=0; $z<$arrlength2; $z++){
   $line = $day[$x]." ".$month[$z]." ".$year[$y];
   
   }
  }  
 //$line = $day[$x]." 2"; 
 //$x++;
 }
$line = implode(",",$line);
echo $line;

Comment: anyone able to help me?

Comment: i made an update to show the code i was using - anyone home?